# Looking for a file-system overlay using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: filesystems, overlay

I'm looking for a shared library that is to be loaded using LD_PRELOAD that would modify the view of the filesystem to the client program.

Ideally, I'd like to choose the filesystem root (or use / as root) and to overlay the filesystem by renaming filenames.

For example, I might want to tell my program to look for /usr/lib/* in /usr/lib32/* instead.

Do you know of such a program ?

Thanks.

Comment: also looking for something like this - to mount an ISO file and read from it without unpacking 10 thousand files

Answer (score 1):

There's [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) which is a little bit like this, but I would certainly not recommend the technique for anything security conscious, since you would have to patch all present and *future* library things that frob files...

An alternate approach might be to make chroot / bind-mount farm. That also has the advantage that you can mount --bind things read-only, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

[PlasticFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plasticfs/) may help, although I *think* (from reading, I haven't tried it) it allows you to effectively create a synthetic filesystem at some mount-point (kind of like FUSE, but using LD_PRELOAD).

So you can e.g create a synthetic root at `/tmp/myfs`, but you would still need a chroot-like tool to present this constructed location as if it were the root of the filesystem. [fakechroot](https://github.com/fakechroot/fakechroot) is an obvious choice for not requiring root, but it also uses `LD_PRELOAD` so I'm not sure if the two tools would confuse each other.

---

*Update:* It's a little confusing, but I've actually tried it now - versions of plasticfs up to and including 1.11 use LD_PRELOAD (and in fact include a "chroot" filter, so you don't need to use fakechroot). So that may be what you want, but:

- it didn't work very well in my tests (created files it shouldn't, missed files that should have been there)
- newer releases (1.11 was released in 2007, it's up to 1.14 now) abandoned LD_PRELOAD entirely for FUSE and a pair of `mount` and `umount` stateful commands, which also removed the ability to use it as a chroot.