# Assistance remembering the name of a Linux “strace”-based tool for file paths mocking

Tags: linux, strace

Once surfing the Internet I’ve seen a home page for a Linux tool which claims it can employ Linux `systrace` interface to execute other programs with manipulated paths. Something like that:

```
$ this-strace-tool --map /home/user1:/home/user2 -- ls /home/user1
  # Outputs content for user2
```

or

```
$ this-strace-tool --map /:/tmp/prefix -- make install
  # Transparently installs into temporary prefix
```

I can recall neither exact tool name nor its options syntax, nor find an appropriate wording for Google query. May be somebody here can remind it to me?

Comment: @JakeGould: no, I'm pretty sure it was a standalone program. But your link also seems helpful.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/143669/looking-for-a-file-system-overlay-using-ld-preload looks promising but doesn't have any answers matching your requirements exactly.