# FUSE fs without root privileges (e.g. a LD_PRELOAD gateway or a proot plugin)

Tags: linux, filesystems, libraries, fuse

On a system where I don't have root access and FUSE isn't installed (or I don't have sufficient privileges to create new mounts), how can I **start a fuse filesytem** (like sshfs or some FUSE-based unionfs) and **access it from (neraly) any program** as made possible by LD_PRELOAD hacks, **without involving the kernel or root privileges?**

I'm looking for an existing **solution like one of these** (or bricks that can be easily assembled to get one of those):

- **An LD_PRELOAD gateway to FUSE**? Does any already exist?
- An **existing plugin for proot** which forwards FS syscalls to a FUSE filesystem (e.g. forwards to sshfs/unionfs/…)
- An existing plugin or extension of another virtual filesytem overlay (AVFS, fakechroot, …) which forwards to FUSE
- **A library providing functions named like `mylib_open`**, `mylib_write`, `mylib_close`… which forward calls to a FUSE filesystem. This would make it fairly easy to patch a specific program when compiled from source (just `#define open mylib_open`) or to patch proot, fakechroot, AVFS or some other vfs.
- Any of the above, using a separate process which replaces the kernel's role (keep hold of mount points and connections with FUSE filesystems, and acts as a server so that multiple client processes may see the same VFS).
- I don't think `qemu-user` could be used to run the real FUSE in its own environment, as qemu-user doesn't emulate the kernel IIUC, and installing qemu-system often requires root nowadays, and trying to run qemu-system without `kvm` would be quite slow.

I found similar questions, but **none addresses compatibility with existing FUSE filesystems**:

- [Looking for a file-system overlay using LD_PRELOAD](https://superuser.com/questions/143669/looking-for-a-file-system-overlay-using-ld-preload) asks about any FS overlay implemented as a LD_PRELOAD, the answers list other FS overlays than FUSE.
- [Presenting a virtual filesystem to a Linux process without root access on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866035/presenting-a-virtual-filesystem-to-a-linux-process-without-root-access) mentions than LD_PRELOADing FUSE would be an acceptable answer, but mostly asks about other similiar virtual FS (and no answer picked that option).
- [Use libfuse in a project, without root access (for installation)? FTP mounts & inotify/kqueue/FSEvents on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321035/use-libfuse-in-a-project-without-root-access-for-installation-ftp-mounts-i) asks specifically about using libfuse without root access to get `inotify` on remote FTP filesystems, and the answers address that specific request.

Comment: Found this research and list of tools by an appkit dev: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/267

Comment: the Goanna project was made for linux 2.6, but was an alternative to fuse based on ptrace: https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/project-goanna.html